# ctree (partykit): how to display horizontal boxplot in terminal nodes for multivariate response

Tags: r, party

I am trying to plot a regression tree generated with the function 'ctree' using the package partykit. Let's suppose the formula used is
y1 + y2 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + ... + xp.
What I would like to achieve is a tree with horizontal boxplots in terminal nodes.
I should be debt full to everyone that will tell me how to achieve this goal.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried and sample data? Please edit **the question** with the code you ran and the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is a placeholder for the name of your dataset.)

Comment: I would guess that this is a suitable example: `library("partykit"); ct <- ctree(Petal.Length + Petal.Width ~ Species, data = iris); plot(ct)`. Creating horizontal boxplots is not directly supported by the package because it typically would not be very helpful. The display created above facilitates comparison of `Petal.Length` across `Species` and `Petal.Width` across `Species` which is what drives the splits in the tree. The horizontal boxplots would only allow comparisons between `Petal.Length` and `Petal.Width` within the same `Species` which would not be of interest.

Comment: If you really want to create the horizontal boxplots, you can also write your own panel-generating function (of class `grapcon_generator`). There are already a couple of posts here on SO that show how to do this. If you provide a concrete example that is compelling enough, I could also have a closer look. But for the typical case (see comment above) I don't think that horizontal boxplots would work well.